# How can I properly display the name of the current ticker on a table when I'm on the extended session?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to display the name of the current ticker (and another one) in the same table. This is the entire code that I'm using:

```
//@version=5
indicator('My Indicator')

ticker1 = input.symbol(defval='AMEX:DIA', title='Ticker')
ticker1_data = request.security('={"session":"extended","symbol":"' + ticker1 + '"}', "", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
plot(close, title='Source', color=color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)
plot(ticker1_data, title='Source', color=color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)

getName(_str) =>
    string[] _pair = str.split(_str, ":")
    string[] _chars = str.split(array.get(_pair, 1), "")
    string _return = array.join(_chars, "")

table1 = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 2)
table.cell(table_id = table1, column = 0, row = 0, text = getName(syminfo.tickerid), text_color = color.new(color.blue, 0), text_size = size.normal, bgcolor = color.new(color.white, 0))
table.cell(table_id = table1, column = 0, row = 1, text = getName(ticker1), text_color = color.new(color.blue, 0), text_size = size.normal, bgcolor = color.new(color.white, 0))
```

I honestly don't even understand how `getName` really works, I just found this piece of code on this site and it usually works.
[image]

The problem is that when I'm on the extended session, the first ticker on the table becomes **"extended", "symbol"**
[image]

I need to freely swicht from the extended to the regular session, so how can I manipulate the string in a different way in order to retrieve the name of the current ticker (i.e. **TSLA**) also when I'm on the extended session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`syminfo.ticker()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dticker)

```
//@version=5
indicator('My Indicator')

ticker1 = input.symbol(defval='AMEX:DIA', title='Ticker')
ticker1_data = request.security('={"session":"extended","symbol":"' + ticker1 + '"}', "", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
plot(close, title='Source', color=color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)
plot(ticker1_data, title='Source', color=color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)

getName(_str) =>
    string[] _pair = str.split(_str, ":")
    string[] _chars = str.split(array.get(_pair, 1), "")
    string _return = array.join(_chars, "")

getName2(_str) => syminfo.ticker(_str)

table1 = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 3)
table.cell(table_id = table1, column = 0, row = 0, text = getName(syminfo.tickerid), text_color = color.new(color.blue, 0), text_size = size.normal, bgcolor = color.new(color.white, 0))
table.cell(table_id = table1, column = 0, row = 1, text = getName2(syminfo.tickerid), text_color = color.new(color.blue, 0), text_size = size.normal, bgcolor = color.new(color.white, 0))
table.cell(table_id = table1, column = 0, row = 2, text = getName(ticker1), text_color = color.new(color.blue, 0), text_size = size.normal, bgcolor = color.new(color.white, 0))
```